# Are Hermitian operators positive?

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators, self-adjoint-operators

I can only find the proof for the reverse statement (i.e. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295874/show-that-a-positive-operator-is-also-hermitian)). However Nielsen Chuang Quantum Computation and Quantum Information p. 90 states the following:

> Suppose we define
>      $$E_m = M^\dagger_m M_m \tag{2.117} $$
>   Then from Postulate 3 and elementary linear algebra, $E_m$ is a positive operator such that $\sum_m E_m = I$ and $p(m) = \langle \psi| E_m| \psi \rangle$.

From the definition it is clear, that $E_m$ is self-adjoint but I am wondering what elementary linear algebra I am missing, since I cant understand why from there it follows, that $E_m$ is positive.

The postulate 3 (p.84-85 can be found in google books) reads in short:

> Quantum measurements are described by a collection $\{M_m\}$ of *measurement operators*.
>   ...
>   If the state of the quantum system is $|\psi\rangle$ immideately before the measurement then the probability that result $m$ occurs is given by
>   $$p(m) = \langle \psi| M_m^\dagger M_m| \psi \rangle, \tag{2.92} $$
>   ...
>   The measurement operators satisfy the *completeness equation*,
>   $$\sum_m M_m^\dagger M_m = I. \tag{2.94} $$

I am guessing that I need to incorporate the completeness equation but I can't see how. Can someone please give me a hint to understand this elementary statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all Hermitian operators are positive (just take the simple Hermitian $1\times 1$ matrix $H= (-1)$ as a counter example). The completeness has also nothing to do with the positivity.

However, an operator of the  form $$E= M^\dagger M$$ is trivially positive. We can show that for any vector $\bf v$, we have that
$$\langle \mathbf v , E \mathbf v\rangle = \langle \mathbf v , M^\dagger M \mathbf v\rangle =  \langle M \mathbf v ,  M \mathbf v\rangle = \langle  \mathbf w, \mathbf w\rangle \geq 0 $$
where $\mathbf w = M \mathbf v$.

Comment: ok that was really elementary. Thanks for the quick insight!